# "Could not authenticate you" during GET requests using twitter npm package

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have discord bot which allows to interact with twitter. When I try to make a GET request, I take **Could not authenticate you.** error. I am using **twitter** npm package.
My code: 
`this.client.tw.get("users/lookup", { screen_name: name }, function (err, data) {
//handling data
}`

Comment: What `node-twitter` version are you using? Can you provide a minimal, reproducible code here?

Comment: I am using 1.7.1.
`this.client.tw` is `new twitter(conf.twitter)` and my config is:
`{
     consumer_key: '...',
     consumer_secret: '...',
     access_token_key: '...',
     access_token_secret: '...'        
    }`